# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when running addToFavourites function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, function, favorites

I have an addToFavourites function, which is causing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.
Basically, I have the Favourites View Controller with a list of all the favourites which the user has added previously, now when clicking on one of the favourites, it pushes the view to a detailViewController, this works fine. On the detail view controller, I have an add to favourites button, this button changes to a remove from favourites if it detects that the key already exists in the addToFavourites dictionary. The problem occurs when the user accesses this detailViewController from the favourites page and also from the main page which lists all the detailViews. They are able to do this as I have a tab bar.

So say I am in the detailView accessed through the favourites page, the favourites button has "remove from favourites", this is correct. But then say I click the remove from favourites button, the button changes to "add to favourites" and removes it from the dictionary. All working fine so far. Now when I switch over to the same detailView, but this time accessed from a different tab on the tab bar, firstly the favourites button still reads "remove from favourites" and when I click this button the first time, it changes to "add to favourites", then when I click it again, I get this EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Here is the addToFavouritesFunction:

```
- (IBAction)addToFavourites:(id)sender {
    NSString *type = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"type"];
    if(type == @"v") {
        NSString *area = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"area"];
        NSString *ID1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"ID1"];
        if([[addToFavouritesDictionary allKeys] containsObject:ID1]) {
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/SavedDict.data"];
            [addToFavouritesDictionary removeObjectForKey:ID1];
            [favouritesButton setTitle:@"+ Favourites" forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
            [addToFavouritesDictionary writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];
            NSLog(@"New Dictionary: %@", addToFavouritesDictionary);
        } else {
            NSString *ID1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"ID1"];
            [addToFavouritesDictionary setObject:Name forKey:ID1];
            [favouritesButton setTitle:@"- Favourites" forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/SavedDict.data"];
            [addToFavouritesDictionary writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];
            NSLog(@"Mutable Dictionary: %@", addToFavouritesDictionary);
            //[addToFavouritesDictionary release];
        }
} else {
        //NSString *area = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"area"]; 
        NSString *ID2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"ID2"];
        if([[addToFavouritesDictionary allKeys] containsObject:ID2]) {
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/SavedDict.data"];
            [addToFavouritesDictionary removeObjectForKey:ID2];
            [favouritesButton setTitle:@"+ Favourites" forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
            [addToFavouritesDictionary writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];
            NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", addToFavouritesDictionary);
        } else {
            NSString *ID2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"ID2"];
            [addToFavouritesDictionary setObject:Name forKey:ID2];
            [favouritesButton setTitle:@"- Favourites" forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/SavedDict.data"];
            [addToFavouritesDictionary writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];
            NSLog(@"Mutable Dictionary: %@", addToFavouritesDictionary);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Check with debugger whether it shows crashing line exactly ...and set breakpoint after that to check for value

Comment: Ok this line seems to be causing a problem : [addToFavouritesDictionary setObject:Name forKey:ID1];

Comment: It seems to be working now, I just retained the Name object in initialization. The only problem now is that the add to favourites and remove to favourites buttons are still different on both detailViewControllers, is there anyway to keep these the same?

Answer (score 0):

Well...either your addToFavouritesDictionary object or your Name object has been deallocated. How are you creating these objects? Either you are releasing them before you should, or you haven't retained them in the first place.

[Objective-C Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not be using the line:

```
if(type == @"v") {
```

What you are doing here is comparing the pointer for the variable `type` to the pointer for the string `@"v"`. Instead, you should use a method that compares the *contents* of the string:

```
if ([type isEqualToString:@"v") {
```

EDIT

The easiest way to keep your titles the same would be to store the text in NSUserDefaults. You could do something like below whenever the button is pressed:

```
// For "Add to Favorites"
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"+ Favorites" forKey:@"ButtonState"];

// For "Remove from Favorites"
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"- Favorites" forKey:@"ButtonState"];
```

Then you would execute something like this when the view loads:

```
[favoritesButton setTitle:(NSString*)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ButtonState"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Oh yea, thanks for spotting that. Any ideas on how to keep the UIButtons title the same on both view controllers? Would I put a method in the viewWillAppear? Thanks